# Mutation operators in local search technique

Tags: python-2.7

I can not find the meaning of  "Number of swaps (chosen at random) per mutation" between two points of a neighbor in Hill Climbing

Comment: ...what? Could you give some more context? Is this even a programming question?

Comment: And who are you quoting? I googled the quote but it's not obvious to me where it comes from?

Comment: Here, we represent a schedule as a permutation or arbitrary, non-temporal ordering of the observations.
Following is an example of **mutation operator:**
Random swap: **Two permutation locations** are chosen at random and the **observation requests swapped, with 1-15 swaps** (chosen at random) per mutation. 
I do not understand how to code of the above mutation operator in Python 2.7. Can anybody please help me?